# Why can't I insert into the database with this code? - JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to insert data into a table based on information from the previous jsp but I keep getting errors. I had print statements to check if the data is transferring and they are. So I think it has something to do with the query statement...

```
    <%= session.getAttribute("userid")%>
    <%= session.getAttribute("deptid")%>
    <%= session.getAttribute("pid")%>
    <%= session.getAttribute("sec")%>

<%
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;        

    Class.forName(driverName);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

    String userdbid = (String)session.getAttribute("userid");
    String userdbdeptid = (String)session.getAttribute("deptid");
    String userdbpid = (String)session.getAttribute("pid");
    String userdbsec = (String)session.getAttribute("sec");

    String query = "INSERT INTO request VALUES("+userdbdeptid+","+userdbpid+","+userdbsec+","+userNetID+")";

    statement.executeUpdate(query);

%>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page
```

at

```
    statement.executeUpdate(query)
```

But when I run something like:

```
    String query = "INSERT INTO request VALUES("575",'76' '01', 'root')";
```

it works just fine

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using parameter substitution.  You are putting the values directly into the string.  Hence, you need delimiters where appropriate:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO request VALUES("+userdbdeptid+", '"+userdbpid+"', '" + userdbsec + "', '"+userNetID+"')";
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I was being a bit too careless

Comment: `PreparedStatement` is not used in proper way. Where is `?` in the query?

Answer (score 0):

In your example you've put the values in quotes, in the code it isn't doing that. Looks like you need to quote your values, presumably they are strings in the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

In the generated sql query there are no quotes.
If you would add a `System.out.println(query);` you would see:

```
INSERT INTO request VALUES(575,76, 01, root)
```

which is no valid sql in your case.

add the quotes in your sql where necessary.